# The getter 'length' was called on null Flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

I am trying to get data from my local JSON file and display it. Everything is ready but I am getting the The getter 'length' was called on null error. It was working in an another emulator but when I changed it stopped working. When I delete length method  The getter [] was called on null.

I looked online but I could not find something that suits me. Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:medicine_reminder/src/ui/homepage/homepage.dart';

class JsonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _JsonPageState createState() => _JsonPageState();
}

class _JsonPageState extends State<JsonPage> {
  List data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 90,
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3EB16F),
          title: Text("Medicine List"),
          centerTitle: true,
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 44, fontFamily: "Angel"),
          ),
        ),
        body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
              child: new FutureBuilder(
            future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                .loadString('assets/csvjson_2son.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              var mydata = JsonDecoder().convert(snapshot.data.toString());

              data.length;
              return new ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                _listItem(index);
                return new Card(
                    child: new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      "" + mydata[index]['ILAC ADI'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.deepOrange),
                    ),
                    new Text("Etken Madde: " + mydata[index]['ETKIN MADDE']),
                    new Text("ATC Adı: " + mydata[index]['ATC ADI']),
                    new Text("ATC Kodu: " + mydata[index]['ATC KODU']),
                    new Text("Barkod: " + mydata[index]['BARKOD'].toString()),
                    new Text("Firma Adı: " + mydata[index]['FIRMA ADI']),
                    new Text("Referans Eşdeğeri: " +
                        mydata[index]['REFERANS \nESDEGER']),
                    new Text(
                        "Eşdeğeri: " + mydata[index]['ESDEGERI'].toString()),
                    new Text("Ambalaj Miktarı: " +
                        mydata[index]['AMBALAJ MIKTARI'].toString()),
                    new Text("Reçete: " + mydata[index]['RECETE']),
                    new Text("Satış Fiyatı: " +
                        mydata[index]['KDV DAHIL PERAKENDE SATIS TL FIYATI']
                            .toString()),
                  ],
                ));
              });
            },
          )),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: Align(
                heightFactor: 13.6,
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => HomePage(),
                        ));
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  _listItem(index) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 32.0, bottom: 32.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              data[index].title,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Text(
              data[index].text,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When using a `FutureBuilder`, you should check if the `snapshot` has the data or is still loading. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59073613/6819340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a `List data;` in your `_JsonPageState` class but you are not assigning a value to it anywhere.

But in the `build` method you are trying to access `data.length;` which will throw the mentioned error since, `data` is still null.

Seeing that you have no use of that line, just remove `data.length`. This will solve your posted issue.

**Secondly**, as @DarShan mentioned, you will face another issue once your current issue is resolved.

Which is, a `FutureBuilder` takes time to load your data from your `future`. So you can't directly access `snapshot.data.toString()` since `snapshot.data` could be null.

So, inside your `builder` add an extra check like this,

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.data == null) return Text('Loading'); // Add this

  var mydata = JsonDecoder().convert(snapshot.data.toString());

  return new ListView.builder(
```

Instead of just returning a `Text('Loading')`, you could also show any kind of a `Loader`.

Comment: But when I removed data.length the error changes to "The method '[]' was called on null". Why is that?

Comment: You are also calling `_listItem(index)` in your code and inside `_lisItem` function you are using `data` again. So remove the `_listItem(index)` line from your `itemBuilder`